# How to connect to ms sql express?

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2008

I have sql express on my local network computer, I created new account, I enabled server auth, and when I am trying to connect to this account from local machine, everything works fine. But when I try to log in from a network pc, it says that login failed for this account. Also, I have disabled all the firewalls.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Is TCP and/or Named Pipes enabled?

Comment: @joeqwerty: Where can I enable this?

Comment: @joeqwerty: enabling this did not change anything

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need to stop and restart SQL after making that change. Did you do that?

Comment: @joeqwerty: yes.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the message you get when you try to connect remotely?

Comment: First post here, so I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong. However, have you turned on the Listener in SQL Server?

Comment: Created a new account where?  A new Windows account or a new SQL Login?  If you created a new account on the PC then you must also create a Windows login for that account in the SQL Server instance.  And then you must also grant that login access at the database level (unless you made the account sysadmin).  Also, what are you logging in with, SSMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fresh install of SQL Server Express will not be functional. You must take additional, manual, steps to complete the installation.

1. Enable TCP/IP.

   By default SQL Server will not be a functional server. For that you need to make it a server by enabling network protocols.

   Click **Start**, **SQL Server Configuration Manager**. Under **SQL Server Network Configuration**, **Protocols for MSSQLSERVER** you can see that tcp/ip is disabled:

   [image]

   Right click **TCP/IP** and select **Enable**. Then you will need to restart the SQL Server service (or reboot the machine if you don't have permission).
2. Enable TCP/IP.

   By enabling TCP/IP you should be able to connect to the server remotely on port `1433`. Unfortunately the Sql Server Configuration Manager does not do everything that is required to enable TCP/IP; it doesn't enable port 1433 on the firewall.

   Click **Start**, **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security**. Right click **Inbound Rules**, and click **New Rule**.

   - Under *"What type of rule would you like to create"*, select **Program**, and click **Next**
   - Select **This Program**, browse to the path to `sqlservr.exe`, e.g.

     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe

     and click **Next**.
   - select **Allow this connection**, and click **Next**
   - ensure **Domain**, **Private**, and **Public** profiles are checked, and click **Next**
   - give the rule a name, e.g. **SQL Server 2012 Express**, and click **Finish**

   The Windows firewall may, or may not, start allowing connections to an existing listening socket. You may, or may not, have to start the SQL Server service (or reboot the machine if you don't have permission).
3. Enable Named Pipes

   The above steps didn't work for me, because SQL Server Management doesn't know how to connect over TCP/IP. You must also try enabling named pipes.

   Click **Start**, **SQL Server Configuration Manager**. Under **SQL Server Network Configuration**, **Protocols for MSSQLSERVER** you can see that Named Pipes is disabled:

   [image]

   Right click **Named Pipes** and select **Enable**. Then you will need to restart the SQL Server service (or reboot the machine if you don't have permission).

Answer (score 0):

I have installed normal instance of sql server (not express), everything works fine on this new instance...

Answer (score 0):

The tricks are as follows:

- Check the errorlog for the problem instance. 
  e.g. the errorlog file here:
  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\" 
  (or wherever your instance is)

There will be lines in there "listening on..."  e.g.
Server is listening on [ 'any'  1129].

- This tells you to connect to that ip on port 1129. In sql client, this looks like this:

servername,1129

or by ip

192.168.66.101,1129   // assuming server is on that ip

- If there is no "listening" line in log, then use the server config tool to enable IP on that SQL instance